# PyQt freezes when showing many widgets all at once

Tags: python, pyqt5, freeze

I am having a problem here. I am basically trying to display every widget in a QVBoxLayout all at once.
The process of creating each row gets completed successfully. However, it seems that once I try to show the main window with `self.showMaximized()` the program freezes. Considering that I am trying to display 400 rows, and each row has something like maybe 50 widgets in it, I am trying to display a lot of widgets all at once, and I guess that the GUI turns unresponsive because of that. What can a viable solution be?
Here is the snipped of code in the MainWindow class that causes the program to freeze:

```
 def display_results(self):
        # Menu Bar
        self.menubar = QMenuBar()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.menubar)
        #Aggiungi menu per oottenere lo storico delle reviews
        Ratings_menu = self.menubar.addMenu("Valutazioni")
        get_negative_ratings = QAction("Ottieni ratings in calo", self)
        get_negative_ratings.triggered.connect(lambda x: self.execute_negative_ratings_dialog())
        Ratings_menu.addAction(get_negative_ratings)
        get_positive_ratings = QAction("Ottieni ratings in crescita", self)
        get_positive_ratings.triggered.connect(lambda x: self.execute_positive_ratings_dialog())
        Ratings_menu.addAction(get_positive_ratings)
        # Aggiungi menu per ordinare i risultati
        sort_menu = self.menubar.addMenu("Ordina")
        #Ordina avendo gli alpha piu negativi in cima
        sort_highest_delta_price = QAction("Prodotti con prezzi competitors piu bassi prima", self)
        sort_highest_delta_price.triggered.connect(self.sort_widgets_highest_delta_price_first)
        sort_menu.addAction(sort_highest_delta_price)
        #Ordina avendo i pilogico piu negativi in cima
        sort_lowest_delta_reviews = QAction("Prodotti con competitors con magior numero di recensioni prima", self)
        sort_lowest_delta_reviews.triggered.connect(self.sort_widgets_lowest_delta_reviews_first)
        sort_menu.addAction(sort_lowest_delta_reviews)

        self.rows = []
        for search in self.searches:
            search_widget = SearchResultWidget(search)
            self.controls_layout.addWidget(search_widget)
            self.rows.append(search_widget)

        spacer = QSpacerItem(1, 1, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.controls_layout.addItem(spacer)

        self.controls.setLayout(self.controls_layout)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.controls)
        
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.searchbar, alignment=Qt.AlignTop)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.showMaximized()
```

Comment: Seriously, 20000 widgets, really?!? I strongly suggest you to reconsider the whole structure of your representation. Even if the framework would support smoothly that amount of controls, it really has no sense to show that many objects all at once. Also, what is SearchResultWidget? What does it do? Are you sure you don't need something else to show your results?

Comment: SearchResultWidget represents a row in my MainWindow. It contains a layout displaying some labels, and a QtableWidget displaying some results and some buttons to interact with its cells. Having all the results displayed is unfortunatly a requirement.

Comment: Frankly, for me it's a bit hard to believe that having 20k widgets visible at once has any kind of benefit. Even in a 4k screen, you wouldn't have more than 20x20 pixel area for each widget, and even when using a scroll area that amount of widget is absolutely *excessive*, especially considering all things that are processed when resizing a window (most importantly, **every** widget is queried about its size hint, and *every* layout computes its contents according to *all* the other layouts. And that makes it even worse if you're using a QTableWidget for each SearchResultWidget.

Comment: Also, you say that you need to show *all* those results at once, but you're using a scroll area, meaning that you actually are not showing everything (and you couldn't). So the only alternatives are to only show a fixed amount of widgets per "screen", use a fake scroll area, or use a QGraphicsView with custom graphics objects. The last option is usually the best for large amounts of objects, but you need to create your own items and possibly limit layout managements (and don't use QGraphicsProxyWidgets!). Right now I cannot think about other solutions, but certainly yours is *not* a valid one.

Comment: Having all those widgets shown at once is a requirement as they are sorted on some of their attributes and it is useful for the user to view those objects listed in such order.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to generate all those widgets on another thread and passing them back to the main thread via a signal once the generation has been completed? 
I know that one problem would be that those new widgets wouldn't be allowed to be added to the main window's layout because they were created in a different thread, but is there any workaround?

Comment: No, widgets can only be created in (and accessed from) the main Qt thread, and anyway it wouldn't change anything since the main problem is how widgets and layouts adjust themselves according to the other widgets and layouts. You must think of other ways to show your data, as having so many widgets and layouts is, let me say, unthinkable. There is another problem also: whenever the window is resized, it'll take *a lot* of time to resize all child widgets. I did a test with just **4 children** for each item, and it takes about 3 seconds for 500 items. Sorry but you *must* find other ways.